# Print function in my DoublyLinkedList creates duplicates. C++

Tags: c++, printing, doubly-linked-list

basically my print function will print out the contents when i only have one Player object inserted into my list.  But when i insert another object, it adds it but the first element inserted has been overwritten.  I have tested my insert and append functions and i dont believe it is to do with these functions.  I think the print function is printing the last entered firstName,lastName,level and exp by the number of nodes in the list.
Here is my code:

***Stats.cpp***

```
#include "Stats.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Validators.h"
using namespace std;

Validators validators2;

Stats::Stats()
{
    firstName = "";
    secondName = "";
    level = 0;
    experience = 0;
}
Stats::Stats(string firstName,string secondName, int level, int experience)
{
    firstName = firstName;
    secondName = secondName;
    level = level;
    experience = experience;

}
    string Stats :: getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }
    string Stats :: getSecondName()
    {
        return secondName;
    }
    int Stats :: getLevel()
    {
        return level;
    }
    int Stats :: getExperience()
    {
        return experience;
    }
    Stats Stats :: input()
    {
        string inputfirstName = "Please enter the First Name: ";
        firstName = validators2.getString(inputfirstName);
        string inputSecondName = "Please enter the Second Name: ";
        secondName = validators2.getString(inputSecondName);
        cout<< "Please enter the level: ";
        level = validators2.getNum();
        cout<< "Please enter the experience: ";
        experience = validators2.getNum();

        Stats s1(firstName,secondName,level,experience);
        return s1;

    }
```

***Main***

```
int main ()
{
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Set up a linkedList and a iterator. 
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DoublyLinkedList<Stats> list;
    DoublyLinkedListIterator<Stats> itr = list.getIterator();
        list.Insert(itr,stats.input());
        list.print(itr);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           DoublyLinkedList.h.
//  Description:    Header file for the use in DoublyLinkedList.cpp.
//                  A DoublyLinkedList is a dynamically growing datastructure and use's
//                  nodes and pointers in its structure.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef DOUBLYLINKEDLIST_H
#define DOUBLYLINKEDLIST_H

#include <iostream>
#include "Validators.h"
#include "Stats.h"

using namespace std;

Validators validators;
Stats stats;


//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Class Declarations.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<class Datatype> class DoublyLinkedList;
template<class Datatype> class DoublyLinkedListNode; 
template<class Datatype> class DoublyLinkedListIterator;
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Class:  DoublyLinkedList.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Datatype>
class DoublyLinkedList
{   
public:
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Member Vairables.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype>* m_head;
DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype>* m_tail;
int m_count;
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Constructor.
//  Description:    Constructs the DoublyLinkedList.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DoublyLinkedList()
{
    //Sets m_head to a default value of 0.  m_head is the first node in the linkedList.
    m_head = 0;
    //Sets m_tail to a default value of 0.  m_tail is the last node in the linkedList.
    m_tail = 0;
    //Sets m_count to a default value of 0.  m_count is to count the elements in the linkedList.
    m_count = 0;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Destructor.
//  Description:    Deletes the DoublyLinkedList.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
~DoublyLinkedList()
{
    //Temporary node pointer.
    DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype>* itr = m_head;
    DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype>* next = 0;

    while(itr != 0)
    {
        //Save the pointer to next node. 
        next = itr->m_next;
        //Delete the current node.
        delete itr;
        //Make the next node the current node.
        itr = next;
    }
}
int getCount()
{
return m_count;
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Append
//  Description:    This adds a node to the end of the list, then points to the newNode
//  Arguments:      p_data - The data to store in the new node.
//                  m_count is increased.
//  Return Value:   None.
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void Append(Datatype p_data)
    {
        if(m_head == 0)
        {
            // create a new head node.
            m_head= m_tail= new DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype>;
            m_head->m_data= p_data;
            m_head->m_next= 0;
            m_head->m_prev= 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // insert a new node after the tail and reset the tail.
            m_tail->InsertAfter(p_data);
            m_tail= m_tail->m_next;
        }
        m_count++;
    }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Print.
//  Description:    Prints the elements from the list along with its index.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void Print(DoublyLinkedListIterator<Datatype> m_itr)
    {
        for(m_itr.Start();m_itr.Valid();m_itr.Forth())
        {
            cout << "------------------Player------------------\n";
            cout << "First Name:\t\t" << stats.getFirstName() << "\n";
            cout << "Second Name:\t\t" << stats.getSecondName() << "\n";
            cout << "Level:\t\t\t" << stats.getLevel() << "\n";
            cout << "Experience:\t\t" << stats.getExperience() << "\n";
            cout << "------------------------------------------\n";
        }
    }
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Insert
//  Description:    Inserts data before the iterator, this works whether the iterator is backwards of forwards
//                  through the list.Inserts at the end of the list if iterator is invalid.
//  Arguments:      p_iterator: The iterator to insert before
//                  p_data: the data to insert
//  Return Value:   None.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void Insert(DoublyLinkedListIterator<Datatype>& p_itr, Datatype p_data)
    {
        if(p_itr.m_node != 0)
        {
            // insert the data before the iterator
            p_itr.m_node->InsertBefore(p_data);

            //if the iterator was at the head of the list,
            //reset the head pointer
            if(p_itr.m_node == m_head)
            {
                m_head = m_head->m_prev;
            }
            // increment the count
            m_count++;
        }
        else
        {
            Append(p_data);
        }
    }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           GetIterator
//  Description:    Generates an iterator pointing towards the current head node
//  Arguments:      None.
//  Return Value:   <Datatype> Iterator
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DoublyLinkedListIterator<Datatype> getIterator()
    {
        return DoublyLinkedListIterator<Datatype>(this, m_head);
    }
};
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Class:  DoublyLinkedNode.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<class Datatype>
class DoublyLinkedListNode
{
public:
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Member Vairables.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype>* m_next;
    DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype>* m_prev;
    Datatype m_data;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           InsertAfter
//  Description:    This adds a node after the current node.
//  Arguments:      p_data - The data to store in the new node.
//  Return Value:   None.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
    void InsertAfter(Datatype p_data)
    {
        //Create the new node.
        DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype>* newNode= new DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype>;
        newNode->m_data = p_data;
        // make the new node point to the next node.
        newNode->m_next = m_next;
        newNode->m_prev = this;

        // make the node before it, point to the new node.
        //if(m_next != 0)
        //m_next->m_prev= newNode;
        m_next = newNode;
    }
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           InsertBefore
//  Description:    This adds a node before the current node.
//  Arguments:      p_data - The data to store in the new node.
//  Return Value:   None.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
    void InsertBefore(Datatype p_data)
    {
        //Create new Node
        DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype>* newNode = new DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype>;
        newNode->m_data = p_data;
        //Set up new Node Pointers
        newNode->m_next = this;
        newNode->m_prev = m_prev;
        //if theres a node before it, make it point to new node
        if(m_prev != 0)
        m_prev = newNode;
    }
};
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Class:  DoublyLinkedIterator.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Datatype>
class DoublyLinkedListIterator
{
public:
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Member Vairables.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype>* m_node;
    DoublyLinkedList<Datatype>* m_list;
    DoublyLinkedListIterator(DoublyLinkedList<Datatype>* p_list= 0, DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype>* p_node= 0)
    {
        m_list= p_list;
        m_node= p_node;
    }

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Start
//  Description:    Resets the iterator to the beginning of the list.
//  Arguments:      None.
//  Return Value:   None.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
    void Start()
    {
        if(m_list!= 0)
            m_node= m_list -> m_head;
    }

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           End
//  Description:    Resets the iterator to the end of the list
//  Arguments:      None.
//  Return Value:   None.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
    void End()
    {
        if(m_list!= 0)
            m_node = m_list->m_tail;
    }

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Forth
//  Description:    Moves the iterator forward by one position
//  Arguments:      None.
//  Return Value:   None.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
    void Forth()
    {
        if(m_node != 0)
        {
        m_node = m_node ->m_next;
        }
    }

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Back
//  Description:    Moves the iterator backward by one position.
//  Arguments:      None.
//  Return Value:   None.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
    void Back()
    {
        if(m_node!= 0)
            m_node = m_node->m_prev;
    }


// ----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Item
//  Description:    Gets the item that the iterator is pointing to.
//  Arguments:      None.
//  Return Value:   Reference to the data in the node.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
    Datatype& Item()
    {
        return m_node->m_data;
    }
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Valid
//  Description:    Determines if the node is valid.
//  Arguments:      None.
//  Return Value:   true if valid
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
    bool Valid()
    {
        return (m_node!= 0);
    }
};




#endif
```

Comment: You are right, your print function is repeatedly printing the stats variable. The question is why did you write it that way? Why did you think that printing the same thing multiple times would do anything different? Anyway I think it's clear that you are trying to compensate for a fundamental error your code has, see my answer. Fix that error, start again, and everything will be much easier second time around.

Comment: Fixed the error :).  Regarding the print function ive tried so many times and different code to get it to print the list and this is the furthest i have gotten so far.  I cannot figure out what to change.  Like im looping through the iterator from start to finish, and then i want to print out the member variables.  I dont undertsand why it is doing that :S

Comment: I think you don't understand iterators. The iterator refers to the value you want to print, you use the iterator to get the value you want to print. All you are doing is using the iterator to tell you how many times to go round the loop, but you are not using the iterator to get anything from the list.

Comment: Post all your list and iterator code. Maybe I'll be able to figure it out.

Comment: K i'll edit it in now.  I did have cout << itr.Item(); which would get the data the iterator was pointing at but it gave me a conversion error.

Comment: OK, now we're getting somewhere. How about `cout << itr.Item().getFirstName()` or maybe `cout << itr.Item()->getFirstName()`. Try both of those.

Comment: cout << itr.Item().getFirstName() worked :).  But how does that work when without the getter it has an error :S

Comment: It's because `cout` does not how to print a `Stats` object. It only knows how to print strings and numbers etc. So you have to break the print down into four parts, first name, second name, level and experience. You know this because that's how you wrote your print function originally, it's just that you wrongly used the stats variable instead of using the iterator. See my new answer.

Comment: Ohhhh right so i can do it this way without using overloading the operator ? Ill remember that next time.  Thank you so much John.:)

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If by overloading the operator you mean writing `operator<<(ostream&, const Stats&)` then that's the other way to do it. That way tells `cout` how to print a `Stats` object, then you could just write `cout << itr.Item();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your print loop should look something like this

```
   for(m_itr.Start();m_itr.Valid();m_itr.Forth())
    {
        cout << "------------------Player------------------\n";
        cout << "First Name:\t\t" << m_itr.Item().getFirstName() << "\n";
        cout << "Second Name:\t\t" << m_itr.Item().getSecondName() << "\n";
        cout << "Level:\t\t\t" << m_itr.Item().getLevel() << "\n";
        cout << "Experience:\t\t" << m_itr.Item().getExperience() << "\n";
        cout << "------------------------------------------\n";
    }
```

See how it *uses the iterator* to get the values to print.

Answer (score 1):

Is this really the code?

```
Stats::Stats(string firstName,string secondName, int level, int experience)
{
    firstName = firstName;
    secondName = secondName;
    level = level;
    experience = experience;
}
```

That's just horribly, horribly wrong. You are assigning variables to themselves! Nothing happens to the object you are trying to construct!

This would work

```
Stats::Stats(string firstName,string secondName, int level, int experience)
{
    this->firstName = firstName;
    this->secondName = secondName;
    this->level = level;
    this->experience = experience;
}
```

but usually you choose parameter names that are *different* from your member variable names, e.g.

```
Stats::Stats(string fn, string sn, int lvl, int ex)
{
    firstName = fn;
    secondName = sn;
    level = lvl;
    experience = ex;
}
```

I'm not surprised you're getting weirdness, you've written a constructor that doesn't work, it's a pretty fundamental thing to be wrong.

Comment: nicely spotted, i didnt see that. :)  Still have the problem though.  I appreciate that.

Comment: Well as I said in my comment above, the code you have written in the print function does just print the same thing over an over. You have to get the value to print *from the iterator*.